# TypeError when styling geojson elements in leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to use leaflet.js to create a choropleth map.  I started with a [geojson of countries](https://github.com/datasets/geo-countries) and added additional information from API data. The geojson now looks like:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ADMIN": "Aruba", "ISO_A3": "ABW", "HW_COUNT": 0, "ISO_A2": "AW" }, "geometry": { "type": ...
```

And is loaded into variable `combined_jsons`.

This code successfully loads the map with the geojson:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 2);
L.geoJSON(combined_jsons).addTo(mymap)
```

Unfortunately, I am having trouble with the next step, which is styling the countries based on `HW_COUNT`.

I used [this example](https://maptimeboston.github.io/leaflet-intro/) to try and structure my styling correctly with this code:

```
L.geoJSON(combined_jsons, {
      style: function(feature){
        var fillColor,
          hw_count = combined_jsons.features.properties.HW_COUNT;
        if (hw_count > 5) fillColor = "#006837";
        else if (hw_count > 0) fillColor = "#78c679";
        else fillColor = "#f7f7f7";
        return { color: "#999", weight: 1, fillColor: fillColor, fillOpacity: .6 };
      }
    } ).addTo(mymap);
```

That returns the `Uncaught TypeError: combined_jsons.features.properties is undefined` error.  I can successfully `console.log(combined_jsons.features[0].properties.HW_COUNT);`, but adding the `[0]` seems to go against the point of the styling, which I assume iterates through every element?

Is there a better way of structuring this layer?

thanks

Comment: The `style` callback takes in a `feature` and not the whole `FeatureCollection`. `L.GeoJSON` iterates through each `Feature` in the `FeatureCollection` for you. So basically you want to use `feature.properties.HW_COUNT` instead of `combined_jsons.features[i].properties.HW_COUNT`, since `style()` will be called a lot of times, and the `feature` argument will take the value of `combined_jsons.features[i]` for every possible `i`.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I updated `hw_count = combined_jsons.features.properties.HW_COUNT;` to `hw_count = feature.properties.HW_COUNT;` and now everything seems to be working. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the property of the current feature and not from all features, also check if the property exists:

```
style: function(feature){
        var fillColor,
          hw_count = 0;
        if(feature && feature.properties && feature.properties.HW_COUNT){
          hw_count = feature.properties.HW_COUNT;
        }
        if (hw_count > 5) fillColor = "#006837";
        else if (hw_count > 0) fillColor = "#78c679";
        else fillColor = "#f7f7f7";
        return { color: "#999", weight: 1, fillColor: fillColor, fillOpacity: .6 };
}
```

Comment: It looks like I didn't even need to be that elaborate. `hw_count = feature.properties.HW_COUNT;` alone appears to have done the trick.  I made sure the property exists when I combined the original geojson and the API-based data, so I think I am safe skipping over the 'check if the property exists' phase. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestions of @IvanSanchez and @Falke-Design, I updated the code as follows:

```
L.geoJSON(combined_jsons, {
  style: function(feature){
    var fillColor,
      hw_count = feature.properties.HW_COUNT;
    if (hw_count > 5) fillColor = "#006837";
    else if (hw_count > 0) fillColor = "#78c679";
    else fillColor = "#f7f7f7";
    return { color: "#999", weight: 1, fillColor: fillColor, fillOpacity: .6 };
  }
} ).addTo(mymap);
```

The change to the fourth line from  `hw_count = combined_jsons.features.properties.HW_COUNT;` to `hw_count = feature.properties.HW_COUNT;` did the trick.

If I had not made sure to add a `HW_COUNT` entry for every country (even when the value was 0), I would have used the @Falke-Design code in order to first verify that the entry existed.